# Unable to see DynamoDB table in localhost endpoint after deploying a Serverless project with Localstack Dynamodb

Tags: typescript, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I am unable to see the DynamoDB table that I am creating in Localstack DynamoDB using Serverless. After sls deploy and sls offline, the Localstack is running on 4566 but I only see TableNames [] not the list of table I created!!
below is my serverless.ts file

```
import { functions } from "@functions/index";
import { ServerlessFrameworkConfiguration } from "serverless-schema";

const serverlessConfiguration: ServerlessFrameworkConfiguration = {
  service: "typescript-template",
  useDotenv: true,
  custom: {
    esbuild: {
      bundle: true,
      minify: true,
      sourcemap: true,
    },
    stage: "${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}",
    stages: ["uat", "alpha", "prod"],
    prune: {
      automatic: true,
      number: 3,
    },
    localstack: {
      stages: ['local'],
      lambda: {
        mountCode: 'True',
      },
      autostart: true
    },
  },
  plugins: ["serverless-esbuild", "serverless-prune-plugin", "serverless-localstack", "serverless-offline"],
  provider: {
    name: "aws",
    runtime: "nodejs16.x",
    region: "ap-southeast-2",
    stage: '${opt:stage, "dev"}',
    profile: 'default',
    environment: {
      AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED: "1",
    },
  },
  functions,
  package: {
    individually: true,
  },
  resources: {
    Resources:{
      customerTable: {
        Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table',
        DeletionPolicy: 'Retain',
        Properties: {
          TableName: 'customertable',
          AttributeDefinitions: [
            {
              AttributeName: 'PK',
              AttributeType: 'S',
            },
            {
              AttributeName: 'SK',
              AttributeType: 'S',
            },
          ],
          KeySchema: [
          {
            AttributeName: 'PK',
            KeyType: 'HASH',
          },
          {
            AttributeName: 'SK',
            KeyType: 'RANGE',
          },
          ],
          ProvisionedThroughput:{
            ReadCapacityUnits: 1,
            WriteCapacityUnits: 1,
          }
        }

      }
    }
   
  }
};

module.exports = serverlessConfiguration;
```

also, docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  localstack:
    container_name: 'localstack-dynamodb'
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    environment:
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=<region>
      - EDGE_PORT=4566
      - services=dynamoDB
      - KINESIS_PROVIDER=kinesalite
    ports:
      - '4566:4566'
```

I am trying to create a table and using mock ids for AWS.

Comment: Are the roles which you use to create and list the tables the same?